# Can you use a path with a wildcard in SET PATH=%PATH%

Tags: batch-file, blender

I have a batch file currently which sets the path for Blender 2.91 then changes the directory so that blender can launch, open a desired .blend file and run a python script. This currently works:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91"
N:
cd ""N:\R^&D\Product_Design\CAD_Drawings\Renders\Render Templates\Creo Direct Integration""
blender -b Creo_Import.blend --background --python Creo_Import.py
```

I want this to run for future releases of blender ie. Blender 3.00 so would like to use a wildcard in the path. I have tried this but it does not work:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender*"
N:
cd ""N:\R^&D\Product_Design\CAD_Drawings\Renders\Render Templates\Creo Direct Integration""
blender -b Creo_Import.blend --background --python Creo_Import.py
```

The error message is "'blender' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

However if I run:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender*"
blender -b Creo_Import.blend --background --python Creo_Import.py
```

Blender will launch with no issues, but the .blend and .py file can not be found as the directory is incorrect. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the point of the double-quotation of your `cd` command line? why not using just one pair of quotes?

Comment: I was having issues with the & in R&D, the solution I found used the double quotes and R^&D. But as you mention it seems that single quotes works with no issue. Thanks

Comment: To begin with `%PATH%` values don't generally include doublequotes, so your first line should read as `SET "PATH=%PATH%C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91"`. And importantly you cannot have a wildcard in a value string location. You should replace lines 2 and 3 with `CD /D "N:\R&D\Product_Design\CAD_Drawings\Renders\Render Templates\Creo Direct Integration"`.

Comment: Thank you. Ok so I will not be able to use a wildcard in this application? Are you aware of an alternative route that I could take on this issue? Or should I just ensure that the multiple users are always on the same version of Blender?

Comment: Yes I do! Do not add the location to `%Path%`, it is unnecessary, and technically slows down scripting, because the environment is growing. You are using a batch file, and the only real purpose of defining a variable in this case is to save a little bit of typing. All you need to do is to locate the blender path for the installed/newest version of the software within the script itself, and use that. It shouldn't be too difficullt to parse the directory names located in `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation`, which contain an executable named `blender.exe`.